# Creating date/time/location class and storing it in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So my goal is to create a class where someone can log in and create an 'event', which really just means they can store a String that is the name of the 'event' (like Woodstock), a future date, and a time that the event starts. I have to store this in a mysql database (I am using LAMP). I've found Joda time, but I have no idea if LocalDateTime can be stored easily in my database (I don't necessarily need time zones as this is a local program but if it needs to have time zones thats fine).

What would also be cool, but I really don't have to implement this but if they could see a calendar for like the next three months or something so they can add the date easily. Anyway, does anyone recommend one format over any others?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, we tend to store our timestamps in milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: Stick with plain [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and you are good to go. No need to add complexity of other APIs if you don't have any complex Date calculations to do. You will also need (maybe) to use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) To format it to your zone (only if needed).

Comment: That is a good point Jorge, can you suggest using DATE vs DATETIME etc in mysql database? I'm just unsure of how to line up the formatting, I guess